# Not parsing JSON data in Swift 1.2

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I have a JSON data which I want to parse it in Swift 1.2.
I found this article and it helped me a lot: http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2015/3/4/populating-a-uitableview-with-json

However in this tutorial the JSON file a little bit different than mine: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=learn+swift+language:swift&sort=stars&order=desc

(There is "items" an array)

Here's mine: (I want to show all rows: row0, row1...)

```
{                       
    "headers": {
        "NOTE_ID": "NOTE_ID",
        "NOTE_NAME": "NAME",
        "SUBJECT": "SUBJECT"
    },
    "row0": {
        "NOTE_ID": "45680",
        "NOTE_NAME": "Do not go there",
        "SUBJECT": "Manchester"
    },
    "row1": {
        "NOTE_ID": "45681",
        "NOTE_NAME": "Watch TV",
        "SUBJECT": "Football game"
    },
    "info": {
        "PageCounter": 17,
        "NoteCounter": "1670"
    }
}
```

I know I need to change this part because JSON in the tutorial has an **"items"** array so it's wrapping there:

```
            if let reposArray = json["items"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                // 5
                for item in reposArray {
                    repositories.append(Repository(json: item))
                }
            }
```

full code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // 1
    let reposURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com/api/notes")
    // 2
    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: reposURL!) {
        // 3
        if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary {
            // 4
            if let reposArray = json["items"] as? [NSDictionary] {                
                // 5
                for item in reposArray {
                    repositories.append(Repository(json: item))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me? 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, I would discourage the use of `contentsOfURL:` for loading a network resource. That's a synchronous call and you never want to block the main thread. If you have a poor network connection and the request takes a little too long, the watchdog process will unceremoniously kill your app.

Comment: your content is an object. the keys in an object are not sorted, and therefore more complex to iterate in a given order. I would recommend changing the format of your data for something like `{"header": {...}, "rows": [{...}, {...}]}`

Comment: thanks for your help njzk2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell because you neither have an `items` entry nor an array. This is a dictionary, where each of the values is, itself, another dictionary.

So, you could do something like:

```
if let reposDictionary = json as? [String: [String: AnyObject]] { 
    // do something with `reposDictionary`, e.g.,
    //
    // for (key, value) in reposDictionary { ... }
}
```

Or, if you want to use `NSDictionary` rather than Swift dictionary:

```
if let reposDictionary = json as? NSDictionary { ... }
```

--

By the way, if the order of these rows is important, you shouldn't use a dictionary (which is unordered), and instead you should change the JSON so that it really returns an array:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "NOTE_ID": "NOTE_ID",
        "NOTE_NAME": "NAME",
        "SUBJECT": "SUBJECT"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "row0": {
                "NOTE_ID": "45680",
                "NOTE_NAME": "Do not go there",
                "SUBJECT": "Manchester"
            }
        },
        {
            "row1": {
                "NOTE_ID": "45681",
                "NOTE_NAME": "Watch TV",
                "SUBJECT": "Football game"
            }
        }
    ],
    "info": {
        "PageCounter": 17,
        "NoteCounter": "1670"
    }
}
```

Or, better:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "NOTE_ID": "NOTE_ID",
        "NOTE_NAME": "NAME",
        "SUBJECT": "SUBJECT"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "NOTE_ID": "45680",
            "NOTE_NAME": "Do not go there",
            "SUBJECT": "Manchester"
        },
        {
            "NOTE_ID": "45681",
            "NOTE_NAME": "Watch TV",
            "SUBJECT": "Football game"
        }
    ],
    "info": {
        "PageCounter": 17,
        "NoteCounter": "1670"
    }
}
```

So have a dictionary with `headers` and `info`, but make `items` an array. Now you can use the following syntax:

```
if let reposArray = json["items"] as? [NSDictionary] { ... }
```

Comment: Nope, the problem is I don't have an "items" field in my JSON Data. In the tutorial, he has. So he used ` if let reposArray = json["items"] as? [NSDictionary] `

Comment: @asking2SOF - My original answer I showed you how to parse the JSON you provided. In my revised answer I show you how to alter your JSON so it can be parsed by the code you provided.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I'm not the one who provides the JSON data. So I can't change it. That's why I want to change the swift code rather than JSON. :(

Comment: @asking2SOF - Then refer to the first part of my answer that shows how to parse the JSON provided. Just eliminate the reference to `items`. Note, if you don't fix the JSON, the order that your Swift code has for the rows may not be the same as the original JSON, unless you manually sort it yourself. Needless to say, the JSON you were provided is extremely poorly designed.

Comment: Thank you Rob. It works fine. I know that it is very bad designed but it is a gov'd data so impossible to me to change it. But would you suggest me to make it a better design in my own host (with php) and then use it?

Comment: Our tax dollars at work, eh? lol. If this is the real source of the data (and presumably will change periodically), I'd suggest writing the Swift code to deal with this poorly designed interface and just call it a day. It's just painful to watch.